# How to fetch only the specific child entity along with its Parent entities with specific value using Spring JPA DATA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, entity

My Entity classes are below,

```
Account
    accountId
    balance
    withdrawls
    deposits
    @OneToMany
    List<CustomerAccount> customerAccounts

CustomerAccount
    accountId
    customerId
    accountType
    customerType (Primary/Secondary)
    @OneToOne
    Customer customer

Customer
    accountId
    customerId
    firstName
    lastName
```

Assume the user searches with
firstName = viki and
lastName = black

AccountRepository

```
findByCustomerAccountsCustomerFirstNameAndCustomerAccountsCustomerLastame(String firstName, String lastName);
```

This query returns both the primary and secondary object even when one is getting matched. I dont want to return secondary, when the firstname and lastname matches with Primary. The secondary should be null and Primary should have response.

But it returns both the primary and secondary. **Is there a way in spring jpa data to return only
the matched child entity along with the Parent entity??**

```
"CustAccnt":{   
    "Account":{
        "balance":"",
        "deposits":""
    },
    "primary":{
         "firstName":"Viki",
         "lastName":"Black"
    },
    "secondary":{
         "firstName":"Noah",
         "lastName":"Morgan"
    }
}
]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the requirement here is to fetch data and process it as well. Some basic processing is possible as part of [open projections](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-projections#2-open-projections). However, your expected processing of Primary and Secondary Accounts as in points 2,3 and 4 below will have to be done in a service layer I'm afraid.

1. fetch all accounts,
2. if both primary and secondary customer match, keep both in account,
3. else if primary customer match, remove secondary customer from account,
4. else if secondary customer match, remove primary customer from account.

Comment: How is this the correct answer and not https://stackoverflow.com/a/64193239/412446 ?

Comment: Pts 1,2,3,4 are like the "question rephrased" what the OP expects. and the answer is that work to be done for 2,3,4 will have to be done in a service layer. @ChristianBeikov. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64193239/412446 is not the right answer, as you can't achieve pts: 2,3 and 4 by the method you have provided. 
`AccountRepository.findTopByCustomerAccountsCustomerFirstNameAndCustomerAccountsCustomerLastameOrderByCustomerAccountsCustomerTypeAsc` - This will return all accounts that match the criteria but will include all `CustomerAccounts` as part of its `customerAccounts` property.

Comment: If one wants to fetch only the matching customer account, it is necessary to write a dedicated query anyway because it's not possible to fetch only a subset of a collection when fetching entities.

Comment: It is still not possible to filter as expected by the OP with JPQL queries either, maybe with native queries and mapping them out to a simple view object with a flat structure. But again, here the object expected by the OP is not an object with a flat structure(It has properties like a list of `CustomerAccount`). So I think it will be difficult, if not impossible to filter it with queries. Easier with filtering logic in the service layer. :)

Comment: Not very hard if I understood it correctly: `SELECT a.balance, a.deposits, p.firstName, p.lastName, s.firstName, s.lastName  FROM Account a LEFT JOIN a.customerAccounts p ON p.customerType = 'Primary' LEFT JOIN a.customerAccounts s ON s.customerType = 'Secondary`

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a bidirectional link from the `CustomerAccount` to the `Account` class and a `CustomerAccountRepository` class which has a method declared `findByCustomerFirstNameAndCustomerLastName` that returns the `CustomerAccount` which links back to an `Account`.

Why the method you have will not work - Account repository only returns Account objects(unless you add JPQL and map the return object to something else). `AccountRepository.findByCustomerAccountsCustomerFirstNameAndCustomerAccountsCustomerLastame`
finds you an(/all) `Account`(/s) that have a `CustomerAccount` with `Customer.firstName` and `Customer.lastname` matching what is provided by the user. The `Account` still has a one to many relationship to `CustomerAccount`, so will contain all the `CustomerAccount`s for the `Account`(in your case both Viki and Noah).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion this might work. But what if both the primary and secondary gets matched with the search criteria. In that case there will be one customer object for Primary and another customer object for Secondary. And if I go with bidirectional then there will be 2 different list for both Primary and Secondary? Any idea on how to handle this scenario ?

Comment: I just tried bidirectional link to the ```Account```  and it still returns both primary and secondary even if only Primary is matched.

Comment: Interesting. I see you have mentioned you have the bidirectional link, but can you confirm that you have added the CustomerAccountRepository and are querying by the below?
CustomerAccountRepository.findByCustomerFirstNameAndCustomerLastName 

or rather CustomerAccountRepository.findAllByCustomerFirstNameAndCustomerLastName 

The first method should give you a CustomerAccount  or if you are using the second method, it should give you a list of CustomerAccount s

And you can get to the Account from the Customer Account using the new link that you said you added.

Comment: As mentioned in my first comments if both the primary and secondary gets matched for a single account. Then it will return 2 different objects i.e list of ```CustomerAccount``` and using the bidirectional link I can able to get the ```Account``` but in that case there will be 2 lists of Account , one will contains the Primary and the other will contain the Secondary. Any Idea of how to handle this ??

_The entity ```Account``` should have both Primary and Secondary if both get matched. Also if only, Secondary gets matched then the Primary should be null._

Comment: I get it now that you need to fetch data and process it as well. Some basic processing is possible as part of [open projections](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-projections#2-open-projections). 
However, your expected processing of Primary and Secondary Accounts will have to be done in a service layer I'm afraid. 
-- 1) fetch all accounts, 
-- 2) if both primary and secondary customer match, keep both in account, 
-- 3) else if primary customer match, remove secondary customer from account, 
-- 4) else if secondary customer match, remove primary customer from account.

Comment: Yeah I don't have idea on projections .. Yes, I think we need to do it in the business logic in the service layer :| Thanks Karthick 

Can you post this as an answer .. will accept it!

Comment: cheers @VikiCullen I have added it as an answer now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to order by the customer type and use the pagination mechanism. If you really must use the method name convention(I hate it, it's unreadable and every query change requires a restart of the application because of method renaming) the method should probably be `findTopByCustomerAccountsCustomerFirstNameAndCustomerAccountsCustomerLastameOrderByCustomerAccountsCustomerTypeAsc`